# Read file with "variable=value" (Windows INI) format?

Tags: python, file

I'm learning Python and as a starter developer I have few questions.

I need read a file that have this format:

```
# This is the text file
[label1]
method=auto

[label2]
variable1=value1
variable2=ae56d491-3847-4185-97a0-36063d53ff2c
variable3=value3
```

Now I have the following code:

```
# This is the Python file
arq = open('desiredFile').read()
index = arq.rfind('variable1=')
(??)
```

But I really don't know how I can continue. My objective is read the value until a new line comes. I think in count the indices between "id=" and the new line, so get the text inside this indices, but I don't have any idea how to do this in Python. Summarizing I want store the values of [label2] in Python variables:

```
pythonVariable1 = <value of variable1 in [label2]>
pythonVariable2 = <value of variable2 in [label2]>
pythobVariable3 = <value of variable3 in [label2]>
```

Note that pythonVariable2 is equals to "ae56d491-3847-4185-97a0-36063d53ff2c" and variables inside the text file have a unique name. So, how can I store the values of this variables in Python variables?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`configparser` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) to handle this instead. That module parses this file format ( called the Windows INI format ) directly.

```
try:
    # Python 3
    from configparser import ConfigParser
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.readfp( open( 'desiredFile' ) )

somevar = config.get( 'label2', 'variable1' )
```

Comment: I will test here, and man, Python is incredible, so exciting. Goodbye Java and Ruby :P

Comment: @FernandoPaladini To be fair there is `java.util.Properties` :)

Comment: I'm having a little error: 'IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied'. It's a file inside /etc/ folder, how I can grant admin privileges to this file?

Comment: Issue solved! Run the .py file with "sudo". And this works!! Thanks guys, thanks python! <3